# Type theory based automated theorem prover?

Tags: logic, type-theory, automated-theorem-proving

I know that there exist type theory based proof-checker, and I know that there are logic/sequent-calculus based automated theorem provers.

But I haven’t heard of a type-theory based automated theorem prover (nor of a sequent-calculus based proof-checker). **Does a type-theory based ATP exist?** (And a sequent-calculus based proof-checker?)

If not, why is it that type theory is more fit for proof-checking, and sequent-calculus more fit for proof-finding?

Comment: Several theorem provers have been [implemented in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Applications_and_libraries/Theorem_provers), which has a built-in Hindley-Milner type inference system.